# Does this reduction mechanism of an diazonium via stannic chloride sense?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Is this mechanism possible.
I didnt find any sources of a mechanism of this specific reaction.
[image]

Comment: That’s not even tin!

Answer (score 2):

Agreeing with Jan's comment, there are a few problems, and they all have to do with your reducing agent. **That's not tin!**

Tin is $\ce{Sn}$ and not $\ce{Zn}$ (zinc). Your mechanism is using $\ce{ZnCl2}$, zinc chloride. Let's say you made a typo and replaced $\ce{Sn}$ with $\ce{Zn}$. Your electron configurations match tin and not zinc. Then your mechanism is good. $\ce{SnCl2}$ is a reducing agent and could do this reaction. $\ce{SnCl2}$ is not stannic chloride, but stannous chloride. Stannic chloride is $\ce{SnCl4}$. Regardless $\ce{SnCl2}$ would work. $\ce{ZnCl2}$ would not work. The zinc in $\ce{ZnCl2}$ is already in zinc's highest common oxidation state. $\ce{ZnCl4}$ does not exist.

Comment: Oh I see i meant Sn (in german) its called Zinn (so i got the letter wrong)

Comment: I expected something similar was the origin of the confusion. If you swap $\ce{Zn}$ for $\ce{Sn}$, your proposed mechanism looks fine.

Comment: I also worked with something different as second mechanism: http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/view/reductionofdiumjq0i3yz1.png